# Vuforia in Unity Recognition only once

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, marker, vuforia

I want to know if there is any way to set the marker recognition to be only once. The reason is that I want to recognize the marker to load a new scene in unity instead of load a 2d/3d content in the current vuforia scene. As soon as the app opens, the camera starts the process of recognizing the AR Marker and loads the content to display in the screen, I only want to know how to recognize the marker once and after knowing that the marker was recognized, load a different Unity scene to continue my workflow inside my app

Answer (score 0):

Inside your ImageTargetPrefav =>DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs

Inside that script:

....

```
private void OnTrackingFound()
{
   //LOAD LEVEL HERE
}
```

That function is on charge to perform the actions when it recognizes the target, so you can load your new level inside that function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it worked perfectly :)